# How to suppress internal method while mocking

Tags: java, unit-testing, mocking, powermock

I want to mock *create* method in MyClient. But when I run the test case, it is invoking *MyClientImpl* constructor and causing issues, as I just want *create* to return my mocked client. I unsuccessfully tried to mock/suppress *MyClientImpl* constructor. Here is what I have done till now

```
public interface MyClient {       
    public static MyClient create(Configuration conf) {
    return new MyClientImpl(conf);
}

public class MyClientImpl {
    MyClientImpl(Configuration conf) {
         //calls to create bunch of other objects
    }
}


@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClient.class})
public class TestClassA {
    MyClient client = PowerMockito.mock(MyClient.class);
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClient.class, new Class[] {MyClient.class});
    //following line causes invocation of create method
    when(MyClient.create(any(Configuration.class))).thenReturn(client);
}
```

Comment: If `MyClient` is actually in interface your example does not compile.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a default dummy constructor and return it with the mock on the static method:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClient.class})
public class TestClassA {

  PowerMockito.mockStatic(MyClient.class);
  //following line causes invocation of create method
  when(MyClient.create(any(Configuration.class))).thenReturn(new MyClientImpl());
}

    public interface MyClient {       
        public static MyClient create(Configuration conf) {
        return new MyClientImpl(conf);
    }

    public class MyClientImpl {
        MyClientImpl(){}
        MyClientImpl(Configuration conf) {
             //calls to create bunch of other objects
        }
    }
```

or you can just suppress the constructor function of MyClientImpl:

```
 /** Suppressing the constructor of MyClientImpl class
          which takes one Argument of Configuration type */
   suppress(constructor(MyClientImpl.class, Configuration.class));
```

You can see more examples and details [in this article](http://www.captaindebug.com/2011/10/using-powermock-to-mock-constructors.html#.Wk8dn1T1VTY) and [here](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/core-java/powermockito/powermockito-constructor-example/) on how to suppress constructors without calling them and you need to prepare both the classes under mock/test.

Comment: The problem is MyClientImpl and MyClient are part of a library. So default constructor is out of picture.

Comment: I tried the suppress, but when following line executes, it calls the constructor :(
       when(MyClient.create(any(Configuration.class))).thenReturn(client);

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the constructor of `MyClientImpl` to returned the mock object:

```
PowerMockito.whenNew(MyClientImpl.class)
     .withAnyArguments()
     .thenReturn(mock(MyClientImpl.class))
```